# Is there a way to disable CTRL + I, tab insertion in .NET UWP WebView

Tags: c#, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I am currently developing a UWP application and I have a WebView control, which a user interacts with. In this WebView, the user can format some text, and I would like for `CTRL + I` to apply italics formatting to any selected text.

When pressing `CTRL + I` the application formats the text (Which is handled using jQuery on the visited site), however, any selected text is replaced with a tab character.

I am aware that the `CTRL + I` keypress event results in keycode 9, which corresponds to a tab character, however, I am wondering if there is a way to disable this interaction?

I have tried intercepting both `KeyDown` and `PreviewKeyDown` events, however with no success. The events never fired, and I am assuming this is because I am entering text inside a webview.
I also checked that the character is not inserted, when opening the visited page, using a normal web browser.

Below is the context of the webview.

```xml
<Page
    <!-- imports -->
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <WebView x:Name="Editor"
                 Source="ms-appx-web:///WebView.html"
                 ScriptNotify="Editor_ScriptNotify"
                 NavigationStarting="Editor_NavigationStarting"
                 NavigationCompleted="Editor_NavigationCompleted"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to disable CTRL + I, tab insertion in .NET UWP WebView

I'm afraid you can't disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> from uwp side. the better way is process multiple key press with javascript in html side.

For example

```
 <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        let keysPressed = {};
        document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
            delete keysPressed[event.key];
        });
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
            keysPressed[event.key] = true;

            if (keysPressed['Control'] && event.key == 'i') {

                event.preventDefault();

                document.execCommand('italic', false, null);

            }
        });

    </script>
    <div id="editor1" contenteditable="true">
        The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
    </div>
</body>
```

You could detect keydown event and disable the default behavior with `preventDefault` method and add the execute new command when  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> pressed like above.

Comment: Thank you a bunch! This was just the solution I was looking for!